# Using Transcribe for EE, can I fall back to the default language where no translation exists?

Tags: transcribe

Im using Transcribe 1.6.1 on EE 2.9 – is it possible to fall back to the default language where no translation is provided?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parameter transcribe="disable" in the channel entries tag